# Find all $(a,b)$ such that $p_b-p_a=a$ and $p_{b-a}=b$

Tags: number-theory

Let $p_n$ denote the $n^\text{th}$ prime number. Find all positive integers $a$ and $b$ such that
$$\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}|p_b-p_a|&=&a\\p_{|b-a|}&=&b\end{array}\right.$$
One solution is $a=1$ and $b=2$ since $p_2-p_1=1$ and $p_1=2$. Another solution is $a=8$ and $b=5$ since $p_8-p_5=8$ and $p_3=5$. I think they are the only solutions since I verified by computer for large integers. How can I prove it?

Comment: But $(a,b)=(5,8)$ is not a solution because $p_b-p_a=19-11=8\neq a$ and $p_{b-a}=5\neq b$.

Comment: I am not sure but you can maybe make some estimations based on the approximation of the prine counting function $x/\log(x)$. At least, that will sort of deal with the very large values for $a$ and $b$

Comment: @Servaes I have slightly edited the question

Comment: @M.Nestor Two people have voted to close this question, citing the reason that it "lacks context".  While I am not one of those two people, I agree that your question could use some improvement.  It would be helpful is you were a bit more explicit in your computation, e.g. write out $$p_8 - p_5 = 19 - 11 = 8, $$ and so on.  Moreover, it would be nice to know where this problem came from (is it an exercise from somewhere?  something you just came up with?) and what makes it an interesting problem to a wider audience.  That is, give some motivation.